# How to avoid error in Selenium click function if there is no button

Tags: python, selenium

I use this code to click on the button on the page with selenium:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle')[0].click()
```

Some pages have this button and some do not. Errors occur on pages where this button does not exist. How can I prevent this error from happening? For example, a condition to check whether this button is on the page or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `NoSuchElementException` or check if the list returned by `find_elements_by_class_name` is not empty:

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

def click_if_exists(class_name: str):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name(class_name).click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print(f'{class_name} element does not exist')
        
click_if_exists('SomeRandomClass')
# SomeRandomClass element does not exist
```

```py
def click_if_exists(class_name: str):
    found_elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name(class_name)
    
    if found_elements:
        found_elements[0].click()
    else:
        print(f'{class_name} element does not exist')
        
click_if_exists('SomeRandomClass')
# SomeRandomClass element does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it under the try block:

```
try:
    document.getElementsByClassName('pv-profile-section__text-truncate-toggle')[0].click()
except Exception as e:
    error = e
```